# How to display SUM value from three EditNumberField() in a Text() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: sqlite, select, sql-update, android-jetpack-compose

Need to display sum value in Total Text() from three user input values in BlueJay, Chickadee, Redpoll EditNumberField()s.

I have tried to do this through a Query and through the code.

QUERY
table name: bird

table columns:
Total, BlueJay, Chickadee, Redpoll

The following query returns the sum of BlueJay + Chickadee + Redpoll as totalcount, but does not display totalcount in the Total column (Update Total with totalcount).

`Select * ,(BlueJay + Chickadee + Redpoll) as totalcount from bird;`

However, since Update from Select is not supported in SQLite, was not able to update total column with totalcount result.

CODE
Lifted and altered the following code from Tip Time CodeLab.
`

```
@Composable
fun BirdCountLayout() {
    var BlueJay by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var Chickadee by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var Redpoll by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    val bluejay = BlueJay.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    val chickadee = Chickadee.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    val redpoll = Redpoll.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    val totalcount = calculateCount(bluejay, chickadee, redpoll)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .statusBarsPadding()
            .padding(horizontal = 40.dp)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            .safeDrawingPadding(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        EditNumberField(
            label = R.string.Blue_Jay,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            value = BlueJay,
            onValueChanged = { BlueJay = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        EditNumberField(
            label = R.string.Chickadee,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            value = Chickadee,
            onValueChanged = { Chickadee = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        EditNumberField(
            label = R.string.Redpoll,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            value = Redpoll,
            onValueChanged = { Redpoll = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.Total, totalcount),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp))
    }

    private fun calculateCount(
         BlueJay: Double,
         Chickadee: Double,
         Redpoll: Double = 15.0):
             String {
                 var totalcount = BlueJay + Chickadee + Redpoll
                 totalcount = kotlin.math.ceil(count)
         return NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(totalcount)
```

`

Problem: onValueChanged for Tip Time,
ex. onValueChanged = { Redpoll = it },
is in conflict with onValueChanged for the database,
ex. onValueChange = { onValueChange(birdDetails.copy(Redpoll = it)) },

The following is a snippet of code (lifted and altered from the Inventory CodeLab) from the database project, for the curious.

`

```
 OutlinedTextField(
    value = birdDetails.Redpoll,
    onValueChange = { onValueChange(birdDetails.copy(Redpoll = it)) },
//       onValueChanged = { OnValueChangeListener (Redpoll = it )},
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.count)) },
    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
    focusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
       unfocusedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
       disabledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
  ),
       modifier = Modifier
          .fillMaxWidth(),
       enabled = true,
       singleLine = true
   )`
```

Is there a way to do something like Update from Select in SQLite? Or, is there a way around the onValueChange limitation? How would you display totalcount in Text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.